Is there something wrong when ios::in & ios::out are conducted to fstream::open() at the same time?
Conducting ios::out & ios::in will lead to something wrong.
When I declared a variable of fstream and opened a file within my work directory with ios::in | ios::out, something wrong occured.

Just only one sort of operation (I/O) can be done normally, and another one can not be done in a normal way.
The operation that can be done successfully depends on the calling order of reading / writing. If reading is run before writing, the reading will be successful, but the writing will be wrong.

When I separately declare ifstream and ofstream variables, the issue was solved.
Here is the source code leading to something wrong:
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int test_001();
int test_002();


int main() {
    // test_001();
    // test_002();
}
int test_001() {
    std::fstream fs;
    // 首先, 如果test.txt不存在, 这串代码并不会创建test.txt
    // 其次, 如果test.txt存在, 只能正常执行读/写操作中最先出现的那种操作(如果先读, 就不能写, 如果先写, 后面就不能读).
    fs.open("test.txt", std::ios::in|std::ios::out);
    fs << "阿米诺斯" << std::endl;
    char* s = new char[1024];
    fs >> s;
    std::cout << s << std::endl; 
}


int test_002() {
    std::ifstream ifs;
    std::ofstream ofs;
    // 首先, 如果test.txt不存在, 这串代码会创建test.txt
    // 其次, 如果test.txt存在, 读/写能正常执行.
    ifs.open("test.txt", std::ios::in);
    ofs.open("test.txt", std::ios::out);
    ofs << "阿米诺斯" << std::endl;
    char* s = new char[1024];
    ifs >> s;
    std::cout << s << std::endl; 
}


I'm sorry, this's my first time to use this platform, and my english level may be very poor.

@NoahMiller In the code that goes wrong you forgot to rewind the stream. fs.seekg(0); fs >> s; Using fs.seekg(0) moves the stream back to the beginning, so that you can read what you have just written. This does not happen automatically.

@john Okey, thanks, I get it. Is there some english grammatical errors ocurred when  i describe the issue i met? i'm a chinese student just get into university. My english level is very poor, haha.

@NoahMiller Your description wasn't perfect but it made sense, especially when I looked at the code as well. The main error you made was posting a picture of your code instead of posting the code itself, but you fixed that and lots of people do the same. Here we prefer to see code posted as text, not as pictures.

A file that is opened for both input and output will likely need to use the seekp, tellp, seekg, and tellg methods.  The p stands for "put" (for output), and the g stands for "get" (for input) — which may be a bit of useful information especially since English is not your native language, and the p/g convention may be a bit obscure (even for English speaking programmers).

Voted to reopen. At least two people understood what the question is about, and one of them provided an answer in the comments. It's a valid question, and undoubtedly confusing the first time you encounter it.

@john Thanks, your answer really gimme a lot of help.

@Eljay Thanks for your answering and consideration. It's really frendly to non-native English speakers like me.

@PeteBecker Haha, it's indeed a difficult problem for me.

@DrewDormann Sorry, i did not it before.And i already fixed it.

Unrelated: You don't have to specify ios::in on an ifstream or ios::out on an ofstream. Those modes are there by default.

For future questions: If the comments in your code is there to guide us, make them in English. Otherwise, remove them.

@TedLyngmo Sorry, I get it.

To begin with, I will note the most important thing: in functions of int type return some value, at the end of each function you should write return NULL; or define them as void type. Next, writing and simultaneous reading should not be practiced, because the same file is opened at the same time. after you finish writing to the file, it is not automatically updated, you should open it to read it. Further, in the "test_001" function, the file is not created because it is also opened in the read mode. If you remove this mode, leaving only fs.open("test.txt", std::ios::out);, the file will be created, then of course you can open the same file with the same variable in the same function in read mode without any problems.
Now, as for the small flaws. All these files should be closed fs, ifs, ofs with var.close(). Also, you use pointers and they should be deleted, since you use an array, it is deleted like delet []s;
I have attached my code solution.
Good job, but delete files, delete pointers too, return values to return functions and don't read at the same time as writing. Go on, good luck, so that your children don't get sick and you are healthy. Bye.
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int test_001();
int test_002();


int main() {
     //test_001();
     //test_002();
}
int test_001() {
    std::fstream fs;
    fs.open("test.txt", std::ios::out);
    fs << "test1" << std::endl;
    fs.close();
    fs.open("test.txt", std::ios::in);
    char* s = new char[1024];
    fs >> s;
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    delete []s;
    fs.close();
    return NULL;
}
int test_002() {
    std::ifstream ifs;
    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open("test.txt", std::ios::out);
    ofs << "test2" << std::endl;
    ofs.close();
    ifs.open("test.txt", std::ios::in);
    char* s = new char[1024];
    ifs >> s;
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    delete []s;
    ifs.close();
    return NULL;
}


You can open them for reading and writing with concurrent stream wrappers, but you do need to call std::ifstream::rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(0, 0) on the reading stream to prevent non-OS buffers from giving you stale reads, and you do need to explicitly flush with std::ofstream::flush on the writing side.

Functions returning an int should return an int e.g. 0. While NULL is technically defined to something that evaluates to 0 it is usually only used in a pointer context, to signify a pointer pointing to nothing. In modern C++ there's a designated keyword to be used for this nullptr which cannot be assigned to an int.

And of course, as the functions always return the same value 0, never something else the question arises why they return something in the first place. The return value does not give additional information. void test_(){...} would make that fact more clear to the reader.
